# dns propogation issue with cloudflare subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, dns, subdomain, cloudflare

Want to configure sub-domain - www.portfolios.shuttrbox.com

when I check DNS propagation for portfolios.shuttrbox.com, it works fine
whereas when I check for www.portfolios.shuttrbox.com it shows all crosses on https://www.whatsmydns.net

Traffic routes through cloudflare
I have my .htaccess configured to add "www" to my domain shuttrbox.com

Not able to figure why www.portfolios.shuttrbox.com is not being propagated.

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general network/hosting tech support.

Answer (score 0):

It was probably a propagation time issue. It appears to now be working correctly.

Comment: actually I added 2 CNAME entries in cloudflare:
1/ portfolios.shuttrbox.com 
2/ www.portfolios.shuttrbox.com

That seems to have worked somehow.

Answer (score 0):

actually I added 2 CNAME entries in cloudflare:
1/ portfolios.shuttrbox.com 
2/ www.portfolios.shuttrbox.com

That seems to have worked somehow.